# Responsive Design using React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this code which is a React app :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from './components/Select/Select';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    Type: [
      {value: 'test 1', name: 'Test 1'},
      {value: 'test 2', name: 'Test 2'},
      {value: 'test 3', name: 'Test 3'},
    ],
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <Select list={[...this.state.Type]}/>
        <Select list={[...this.state.Type]}/>
        <Select list={[...this.state.Type]}/>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Also I have the code for my component Select :

```
import React from "react";

const selectoption = ({ list }) => (
    <select className="custom-select">{list.map(option => (<option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>))}
    </select>
);

export default selectoption;
```

I got this :

[image: Original]

But I would like to have this :

[image: Goal]

I mean I want the 3 select wrap content.

Also,

I don't know how to do this but when I reduce the size I got this :

[image: Original]

whereas I would like to have this :

[image: Goal]

Do you know how can I do this easily ?

Thank you very much !!!

NB : my code is there :https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wood-83cg3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)? That would make it easy to convert to a responsive design.

Comment: I looked at this library but I am not sure it works like what I want unfortuntely :/

Comment: If react bootstrap isn't a solution for you, try [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The `window.innerWidth` property gives the viewport width. If it is less than 500, the user is using a mobile phone. Using this information you can implement conditional styles that result in the page being responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Just with CSS here. You only need to wrap these `Select`components with a `div` then styling it.

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <Select list={[...this.state.Type]} />
    <Select list={[...this.state.Type]} />
    <Select list={[...this.state.Type]} />
</div>
```

In `styles.css`:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    width: 100%;
}
```

or another way you want

Don't forget to import the CSS file into the `App` component

```
import "./styles.css";
```

Comment: Thank you it is almost that but I have still the last case (see my last pics)

Comment: Something wrong with my solution? I also work as you last pic: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pond-00t8l

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has built-in classes that will produce your desired responsive behavior.

The HTML:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body style="padding: 1rem">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <select class="custom-select col-md-4">
        <option value="test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test 2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="test 3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
      <select class="custom-select col-md-4">
        <option value="test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test 2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="test 3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
      <select class="custom-select col-md-4">
        <option value="test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test 2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="test 3">Test 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

The equivalent JSX would be:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
  <div className="row">
    <Select className={"custom-select col-md-4"} list={[...this.state.Type]} />
    <Select className={"custom-select col-md-4"} list={[...this.state.Type]} />
    <Select className={"custom-select col-md-4"} list={[...this.state.Type]} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you also need to link the bootstrap css, in your index.html file (if you have one).